# How to suppress TTS.getAvailableLocales()'s warning messages

Tags: android, text-to-speech, logcat

I can get a list of supported locales for the current device iterating like this :

```
for (Locale each : Locale.getAvailableLocales())
    if(1 <= myTTS.isLanguageAvailable(each))
        supportedLocales.add(each);
```

But my problem is, the method `isLanguageAvailable()` always logs the warning messages for unsupported locales like this :

```
08-15 20:10:08.163  5056    5672    W   TTS Local voice not installed, we will not be able to do local fallback
08-15 20:10:08.527  5056    5067    W   TTS No local or network voice found, failing dispatch
08-15 20:10:08.527  5056    5067    W   TTS Could not find voice for lkt_US
08-15 20:10:08.606  24353   24382   W   TextToSpeech    Couldn't retrieve ISO 3166 country code for locale: es_EA
08-15 20:10:08.606  24353   24382   W   TextToSpeech    java.util.MissingResourceException: Couldn't find 3-letter country code for EA
08-15 20:10:08.606  24353   24382   W   TextToSpeech        at java.util.Locale.getISO3Country(Locale.java:1720)
08-15 20:10:08.606  24353   24382   W   TextToSpeech        at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$16.run(TextToSpeech.java:1789)
08-15 20:10:08.606  24353   24382   W   TextToSpeech        at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$16.run(TextToSpeech.java:1777)
08-15 20:10:08.606  24353   24382   W   TextToSpeech        at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$Connection.runAction(TextToSpeech.java:2301)
08-15 20:10:08.606  24353   24382   W   TextToSpeech        at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.runAction(TextToSpeech.java:752)
08-15 20:10:08.606  24353   24382   W   TextToSpeech        at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.runAction(TextToSpeech.java:742)
08-15 20:10:08.606  24353   24382   W   TextToSpeech        at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.isLanguageAvailable(TextToSpeech.java:1776)
08-15 20:10:08.606  24353   24382   W   TextToSpeech        at com.jyplugin.ttsforandroid.TTSEngine.getAvailableLanguageNames(TTSEngine.java:155)
08-15 20:10:08.606  24353   24382   W   TextToSpeech        at com.jyplugin.ttsforandroid.TTSEngine.getAvailableDisplayNames(TTSEngine.java:190)
08-15 20:10:08.606  24353   24382   W   TextToSpeech        at com.jyplugin.ttsforandroid.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:45)
08-15 20:10:08.606  24353   24382   W   TextToSpeech        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

I get a bunch of these whenever I launch my TTS app and I really don't want this.

How can I suppress these unwanted warning messages for my release version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One workaround is to set your logcat filter to everything but TextToSpeech (you need regex enabled): `^((?! TextToSpeech).)*$`

I don't think you can do anything about the logs that come from the core api. The same issue is present when you debug from some phones and get bluetooth or connection logs ALL THE TIME.

Answer (score 1):

Since API 21, you can call [your tts instance].getAvailableLanguages() and it will return a Set of supported Locales instead of iterating the way you're doing.

One important thing to note, though, is the getAvailableLanguages() method is not guaranteed to supply properly formatted Locales... for example, Samsung TTS Version 201503021 running on API 23 will return three-letter language and country codes.  Derp.

What this means is that you can't necessarily go on to use these same Locale objects to do a setLanguage() or isLanguageAvailable()... because TTS objects *do* rely on the Locales you supply being properly formatted. :(

The Google engine appears to supply proper Locales, though... and if you have a set of Locales you have acquired from the system, such as:

```
    // Get all locales from user's preferred list (API 24+) or the single preferred locale (API<24)
    LocaleListCompat systemLocaleList = ConfigurationCompat.getLocales(Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration());
```

... then you can do isLanguageAvailable() in a loop the same way you are doing.